# Updating lines in terminal while doing other stuff on the last one in Python?

Tags: python, terminal, console, console-application, scheduling

I am trying to write a Python program that tracks the prices of the stock market and outputs it to the user refreshing the same line through stderr, that's a simplified version of the code (used randint just to check that the program was doing something):

```
import random
import schedule
import time
import sys

def printran():
    a = "\rFirst Line is: " + str(random.randint(1,10))
    sys.stderr.write(a)

schedule.every(2).seconds.do(printran)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

My problems are:

a) How do I "refresh"the console output on multiple lines?

I tried stuff like:

```
a = "\rFirst Line is: " + str(random.randint(1,10)) + "\n\rSecond Line is: " + str(random.randint(2,20))
```

but the output is a mess and obviously the \n command will always generate a new line

b) since the while function doesn't really end I cannot do other stuff, do I need to use multithreading?

c) finding a solution that is as much as possible easy, portable and OS agnostic (must work on Linux, OSX, Win).

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import schedule
import threading
import time

def printran():
    print("First Line is: " + str(random.randint(1,10)))


def run():
    schedule.every(2).seconds.do(printran)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = threading.Thread(target=run)
    t.start()
```

Also, you can use [APScheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
But in the following code `sched.start()` won't wait and it will stop with main.

```
import random
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import time

def printran():
    print("First Line is: " + str(random.randint(1,10)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sched = BackgroundScheduler()
    sched.add_job(printran, 'interval', seconds=2)
    sched.start()
    # wait 10 seconds and exit
    time.sleep(10)
```

Should be crossplatform (I didn't check on Win, Mac, but it works on linux)